# SPSS: How to arrange counts and percentage in horizontal order?

Tags: spss

The usual crosstabulation table in spss looks like this:

```
                               Variable 2
                               category A
                           Counts    Percentage
Variable 1    category1    value1    per1
              category2    value2    per2
```

How do I do it in spss such that the table will look like this? Is this possible using some syntax?

```
                                          Variable 2
                                          category A
Variable 1    category1    Counts         value1    
                           Percentage     per1
              category2    Counts         value2    
                           Percentage     per2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if the [`CROSSTAB`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_crosstabs.htm) command does produce the table as you indicate?

Using the `Employee Data.sav` data shipped with SPSS and the below example

```
GET FILE="C:\PROGRAM FILES\IBM\SPSS\STATISTICS\24\SAMPLES\ENGLISH\EMPLOYEE DATA.SAV".
CROSSTABS
  /TABLES=gender BY minority
  /FORMAT=AVALUE TABLES
  /CELLS=COUNT ROW
  /COUNT ROUND CELL.
```

I get the below, which looks like it is in your desired format?

[image]

Alternatively, if you have access to SPSS add-on module `CUSTOM TABLES` then there is great deal of flexibility to change table structures.

### EDIT:

Using `CUSTOM TABLES` you can use the `/SLABELS POSITION={ROW|COLUMN}` subcommand to specify how you would like statistics to be presented:

```
CTABLES
  /TABLE gender [COUNT F40.0 COLPCT.COUNT] BY minority
  /SLABELS POSITION=ROW.
```

The equivalent can be found in the `CUSTOM TABLE` GUI also:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jignesh, yes I have custom table. I'm sorry I should have indicated that I used custom Table. I do not know how to do it in order to achieve my desired format. yet, thank you for suggesting crosstab command. I will try it.

Comment: I find `CTABLE` more versatile so tend to use `CTABLE` for almost all tabulating (unless if needing a very quick and dirty crosstab). Edited answer to provide some guidance how to achieve using `CTABLE`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is what I need :D :D :D